# How to revoke permission form a folder?

Tags: permissions, sudo

There are multiple users in ubuntu in my system.
Let's say users are `X1`, `X2`, `X3`, .. , `Xn`

Now in a Storage HD mounted at `/data/` each of them contains one folder.
User `X1` is sudoers. Each time a new user (`X*`) comes, `X1` creates a new folder by his username (`X*`) in `/data/` and gives permission by

```
setfacl -m u:X*:rwx X*
chown X* X*
```

Now to see the folder persmission we use,

```
# file: X*
# owner: X*
# group: N1
user::rwx
user:X*:rwx
group::rwx
mask::rwx
other::r-x
```

Now every user in the usergroup can see the folder content of other users.  as they can enter to each other's designated folder. How to restrict them each entering other's folder.

Comment: Seems to me that using ACL is overkill here; just `chown` to the user and do a `chmod g=,o=`.

Comment: How to restrict them each entering other's folder ? With good practice of ACL... Please write real commands and paths used.  Q: "X1 creates a new folder " do you mean a human does it manually? (Reply with @cmak or i wont get in touch)

Comment: @cmak yes, an writes call a command, "mkdir X*"

Comment: @fkraiem haven't understood. can you write a full answer?